# Customized button with image and text

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]
How can I create a Button with selectable image on left side of button and text on right side of the same button using storyboard and programmatically?

I want to display a radio type image and text on the button !!!

Comment: You should create a custom view and then add separate button for image and label for title

Comment: show some UI...

Comment: @UsamaSadiq, not a good suggestion, `UIButton` allow to set `image` as well as text. so no need to add `image` and `label` separately.

Comment: @Sudhir `Image` contains `cell` or what?

Comment: IMHO, `UIButton` is a pain in the ... when using custom images. I always create separate labels and image views, that's a lot easier.

Comment: if we implement custom `images` and `label`, there's much coding to implement, suppose there's 50 buttons than instead of creating 500 `image` and 50 `label` i go for `button`.

Comment: @Pankhil , its a custom view cell with label and button it , i want to display some text along with the image in button

Comment: @Sudhir, Below answer is good but it will not work in `UITableViewCell`. **Reason:** when you scroll your `tableView` selected button are mismatch.

Comment: @Pankil, true, which is why I actually created a custom control that acts exactly like a button: it has a tap gesture recognizer and you connect title label and image view (both optional) and when setting the title it automatically sets the label's text, same for the image view :)

Answer (score 1):

Add text and image name as mentioned on the screen attached. You can select different icons for different button state as mentioned in the screen attached

If you further want to customize create your custom view with title and image. See [this post](https://medium.com/@Kirillzzy/create-a-custom-button-for-ios-e81026bd6148) on how to create a custom button

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find a demo with two UI buttons On & Off with screenshots.

1.Set the button image & text you want.

[click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTeRS.png)

2.Set the horizontal alignment to left(you can set the alignment as per your requirement).

[click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bXnz.png)

3. If you want space between your image & text, you can set the title insets.

[click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QINJn.png)

4. Here is the final result of the button.

[click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Wuc.png)